# Excel Macro to add rows until today's date and update following columns accordingly

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I got an excell sheet with 3 worksheets that I update like every 2-3 days manually by dropping down the date column and it automatically updates the columns based on the date.

For example: Let's say I opened the Excel on april 4th, what I do is I drop down the date and until *today -1* and following columns gets updated automatically.

I basically add in 2 more rows to the worksheet and and columns get updated based on the date.

```
01.04.2016    12       15      16     19
```

I would like to make a macro which adds in those needed rows (If i no one updated the Excel for like 10 days it needs to add in 9 rows etc) when I hit the button for 3 worksheets at once.

Thanks alot.

Comment: To simplify and express myself better; I want this macro to check last row with data and drop down the formulas until last entry on column A (which is date) is equal to Today's date. Basically last row will be indicating T-1.

Comment: please note that superuser is not a free code writing service. We ask for specific questions (e.g. why this line of macro doesn't work), but don't provide entire solutions.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure how the values are determined from the date. Please [edit] your question with more details about how that works.

Answer (score 1):

There are more efficient solutions, but this one is fairly straightforward and makes it relatively easy to see exactly what your code is doing:

Look at "OFFSET" and "END(XLDOWN)"
OFFSET(+/-# of rows,+/-# of columns)
Example: `selection.offset(-1,0)` refers to the cell directly above the selected cell, while `selection.offset(1,1)` refers to the cell one down and one to the right from the selected cell

Move the cursor to the last date in the column:
(Presumes "A1" contains the first date in your list; change accordingly)

```
range("A1").end(xldown).select
```

Add new dates and fill in formulas until the desired date is reached:

```
do until selection = date-1
'select the next empty cell in the date column
selection.offset(1,0).select
'enter the date
selection.value = selection.offset(-1,0).value +1
'update each column
'repeat for each column as needed
'same row, one column to the right, getting formula from the cell above it:
selection.offset(0,1).formula=selection.offset(-1,1).formula
'same row, three columns to the right, getting formula from the cell above it:
selection.offset(0,3).formula=selection.offset(-1,3).formula
'after updating all desired columns, go to the next date:
loop
```

You can just repeat the code for each worksheet(not recommended):

```
sheets("name").select
'code
sheets("name2").select
'code
'etc.
```

or set up a loop for the worksheets:

```
for a = 1 to 3:
sheets(a).select
'code
next a
```

If your workbook contains more than three sheets, you'll need to test the sheet names:

```
for a = 1 to activeworkbook.sheets.count
select case sheets(a).name
case "name,name2,name3":
'code
case else:
'do nothing
end select
next a
```

Again, these aren't necessarily the most elegant solutions, but they should give you a solid start on building your macro.